# Handling mail draft ( i.e. MFMailComposeResultSaved ) in MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Am writing a simple App (using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5, using iOS Simulator to test). This sends email and the email composition window opens up in a non-modal form, as usual. One of the possible results of the email composition is 'save as draft' i.e. MFMailComposeResultSaved. How do I retrieve the saved draft in such a case? Or better yet, can I do away with this option ? (i.e. even if the user makes any modification in the 'mail compose' window, it should *not* show 'save as draft' option. Any help please?

**In ViewController.h (header file)**

```
-(void)showEmailComposer;
-(void) displayComposerSheet;
```

**In ViewController.m file:**

```
-(void)showEmailComposer {

    NSLog(@"showEmailComposer: begin");

Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil)
{
    if ([mailClass canSendMail]) {
        NSLog(@"showEmailComposer: Calling displayComposerSheet");
        [self displayComposerSheet];

    }
}
 }


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Compose Mail

-(void) displayComposerSheet {
mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
}


-(void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

NSString *alertTitle;
NSString *alertMsg;

// Notifies users on errors, if any
switch (result) {

    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        alertTitle = @"Cancelled";
        alertMsg = @"Mail composition got cancelled";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        alertTitle = @"Success - Saved";
        alertMsg = @"Mail got saved successfully!";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        alertTitle = @"Success - Sent";
        alertMsg = @"Mail sent successfully!";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        alertTitle = @"Failure";
        alertMsg = @"Sending the mail failed";
        break;
    default:
        alertTitle = @"Failure";
        alertMsg = @"Mail could not be sent";
        break;
}

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                      initWithTitle:alertTitle
                      message:alertMsg
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a user choose saving mail to draft, the mail is in the '**Draft**' directory of '**Mail**' application. If user choose sending the mail, the mail is in the '**Outbox**' directory of '**Mail**' application. So my suggestion is, informing the user of the fact that, '**Mail**' application is responsible for mail sending and editing.